# Upgrading to outlook 2013 killed a a VBScript - image in table

Tags: image, vbscript, outlook, outlook-2013

I have cut down the script to be as simple as possible. The issue is inserting an image in a table for Outlook 2013. This script works with older versions.

1 table, 1 row, 2 columns and using the AddPicture in a cell kills the script!

`objTable.Cell(1, 1).Range.Text = objSelection.InlineShapes.AddPicture(strLogo)`

Full script below. Any work arounds would be appreciated.

```
'-------------
On Error Resume Next
Set objSysInfo = CreateObject("ADSystemInfo")
strUser = objSysInfo.UserName
Set objUser = GetObject("LDAP://" & strUser)

strName = objUser.FullName
strMail = objuser.mail
strLogo = "c:\1.jpg"

Set objWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
objWord.Visible = False

Set objDoc = objWord.Documents.Add()
Set objSelection = objWord.Selection
Set objRange = objDoc.Range()

Set objEmailOptions = objWord.EmailOptions
Set objSignatureObject = objEmailOptions.EmailSignature
Set objSignatureEntries = objSignatureObject.EmailSignatureEntries

objDoc.Tables.Add objRange, 1, 2
Set objTable = objDoc.Tables(1)
objTable.Cell(1, 1).Range.Text = objSelection.InlineShapes.AddPicture(strLogo) 
objTable.Cell(1, 2).select
objSelection.TypeParagraph()
objSelection.TypeText strName
objSelection.Font.Bold = false
objSelection.TypeParagraph()
objSelection.TypeText strMail

objSignatureEntries.Add "Signature", objRange
objSignatureObject.NewMessageSignature = "Signature"
objSignatureObject.ReplyMessageSignature = "Signature"

objDoc.Saved = True
objWord.Quit
'----------------
```

Comment: VBScript debugging 101: remove global `On Error Resume Next`, so you can actually see what breaks.

Comment: Any `On Error Resume Next` that spans more than five lines of code can be considered a bug. You should *absolutely never* use it as the first statement in your script.

Answer (score 2):

Your error is obvious:

```
objTable.Cell(1, 1).Range.Text = objSelection.InlineShapes.AddPicture(strLogo)
```

this cannot work because you try to assign to `.Text` something that is not a string. Moreover: This has never worked, you just never noticed.

`.AddPicture()` already does all you want, just select the right spot in the document before:

```
objTable.Cell(1, 1).Select
objSelection.InlineShapes.AddPicture(strLogo)
```

Apart from this your script violates a few basic rules.

- Always use `Option Explicit`. No exceptions, no "but", no arguments with "quick" or "only".
- Never use `On Error Resume Next` as a global setting.
- Write functions/subs to wrap up steps that can fail. `On Error Resume Next` has function scope, you can switch it on in a function to guard a line that can throw an error and it will be reset when the function ends.
- If you can't/don't want to create an extra function, use `On Error Goto 0` to end the effect of `On Error Resume Next` *as soon as possible*, but not before you've checked the `Err` variable to handle the error yourself.
- Write functions/subs to structure your code.
- A matter of preference, but I like to use `With` blocks.
- Another matter of preference, but Hungarian notation makes no sense. By convention I use `PascalCase` for objects and `camelCase` for primitive values (strings, numbers, dates), along with speaking variable names.

Here's an improved version:

```
Option Explicit

Dim User, logo

Set User = GetCurrentUser
logo = "C:\1.jpg"

If Not User Is Nothing Then
  CreateEmailSignature User, logo
Else
  WScript.Echo "Could not retrieve user from AD."
End If
'------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Function GetCurrentUser()
  Set GetCurrentUser = Nothing

  On Error Resume Next
  Set GetCurrentUser = GetObject("LDAP://" & CreateObject("ADSystemInfo").UserName)
End Function
'------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Sub CreateEmailSignature(ADUser, logoPath)
  Dim Doc, Table

  With CreateObject("Word.Application")
    Set Doc = .Documents.Add
    Set Table = Doc.Tables.Add(Doc.Range, 1, 2)

    Table.Cell(1, 1).Select
    InsertPictureFromFile .Selection, logoPath

    Table.Cell(1, 2).Select
    .Selection.TypeParagraph
    .Selection.TypeText ADUser.FullName
    .Selection.Font.Bold = False
    .Selection.TypeParagraph
    .Selection.TypeText ADUser.Mail

    With .EmailOptions.EmailSignature
      .EmailSignatureEntries.Add "Signature", Doc.Range
      .NewMessageSignature = "Signature"
      .ReplyMessageSignature = "Signature"
    End With

    Doc.Close False
    .Quit False
  End With
End Sub
'------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Sub InsertPictureFromFile(Selection, picturePath)
  On Error Resume Next
  Selection.InlineShapes.AddPicture picturePath
End Sub
'------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Thank you @Tomalak for your updated code. I understand the need for functions and the unnecessary use of global variables, so thanks for the heads up.
Unfortunately I now receive the following error on Table.Cell(1,2).Select
_The remote server machine does not exist or is unavailable: 'Table.Cell'_
Any ideas?

Comment: On further investigation it is still the _Selection.InlineShapes.AddPicture picturePath_ which is causing the issue. :(

Comment: The code in my works for me, I've tested it. On what line does the error occur? In `AddPicture`? Sounds a bit like `picturePath` would contain the string "Table.Cell", which is completely implausible.

Comment: Well I think it is an environment issue. It works as expected on a Windows 2008 R2 Server with Outlook 2010 but not on my local PC (Windows 8.1) or our new server (Windows 2012) both with Office 2013.

Comment: The error message says *"The remote server machine does not exist or is unavailable: 'Table.Cell'"*. It obviously tries to talk to a remote machine named `Table.Cell`. This does not even make sense. There can't be many reasons for this and I'm pretty certain "Windows 8" or "Office 2013" are none of them.

Answer (score 0):

I found out that it is a 64 bit Office issue. 
I have reinstalled on multiple pc's using 32 bit Office 2013 and everything works as it should.